# iOS-13 - CornerRadius of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I had set the cornerRadius of the layer of a `UITableViewCell` in its `init` method. It used to work in iOS 12 and 11, but it does not work in the latest version of iOS: iOS 13.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}
```

The cell has border, but when I swipe left(trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt) the cell misses its border.

How to set `cornerRadius` of `UITableViewCell` in iOS 13?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your `cornerRadius` modification in `UITableView`'s `contentView` instead. Apple might have restricted layer modifications for `UITableView`s in iOS 13.

EDIT: do any of your view modification in `UITableView`'s `contentView` property. In runtime, iOS performs other operations in the `UITableView`'s root view. I had an issue way back wherein I cannot do tap actions inside a `UITableView` cell in iOS 10, the way I fixed it is I moved everything inside `contentView`.